# Code with await Promise.all() doesn't continue in execution

Tags: javascript

I've got troubles with awaiting `Promise.all()`, it never continues after that. I've got helper function for creating cancelable promises:

```
create(promise) {
    let hasCanceled_ = false

    const wrappedPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      promise.then(
        val => (hasCanceled_ ? reject({ isCanceled: true }) : resolve(val)),
        error => (hasCanceled_ ? reject({ isCanceled: true }) : reject(error))
      )
    })

    const cancelablePromise = {
      promise: wrappedPromise,
      cancel() {
        hasCanceled_ = true
      }
    }

    return cancelablePromise
  }
```

then I created promises like following way:

```
const timelinePromise = this.pendingPromises.create(
    this.fetchWholeTimeline(false)
)
const confJobsPromise = this.pendingPromises.create(
    this.fetchWorkspaceJobConfigurationJobs(false)
)
```

and at least I'm executing this piece of code:

```
const [timelineResponse, confJobsResponse] = await Promise.all(
    timelinePromise.promise,
    confJobsPromise.promise
)

console.log(timelineResponse)
console.log(confJobsResponse)
```

The `console.logs` are never executed... What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Btw, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). Your `create` function should simply do `promise.then(result => { if (hasCancelled) throw {…} else return result; }, err => { if (hasCancelled) throw {…} else throw err; })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all` expect an array (iterable actually) of promises as the single parameter.

Comment: Lol, how could I missed such a thing ... and it's not friday yet :D

Answer (score 0):

the Promise.all method expects an array of promisses.

```
Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB])
```